# Sumif + Index/Match

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, index-match

Essentially I am trying to find the sum in column A that corresponds to names distributed in the array to the right. Below is a picture of what I am trying to do and what my formula is as of now. Please let me know either how to modify my formula or how to restructure my data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhDSW.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:G14="",,B2:G14&"×"&A2:A14)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'Totals'")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula I came up with that can accomplish this:

`=sum(filter($A$2:$A$11, arrayformula(REGEXmatch(ARRAYFORMULA((IF(ROW($A$2:$A$11)=1,"formulaTest",$B$2:$B$11 & $C$2:$C$11 & $D$2:$D$11 & $E$2:$E$11 & $F$2:$F$11))),B13))=TRUE))`

This formula should be placed in the cell below `Name1`, next to `Totals`, and then copied across the row under each name. The cell references should be changed to match your sheet/needs. Anything with `$` before it defines either the duration column, or each column that contains the names. The last cell reference (`B13`) is a reference to the cell that contains the name you are looking to total. A screenshot of an example of this is shown at the bottom of this answer.

In simple terms, this formula combines the names from each row into a single string (per row), searches for each name within that combined string, filters the duration value if there is a match, and then sums that value.

[image: example]

Hope this helped! Let me know if there is anything I should explain further or better clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The most helpful part of your answer was that this formula combined the names into one string. This is how I had the data before. I recombined it and then used REGEXMATCH to count which cells had each name in it. Then I used SUMIFS to sum based off the name and another category. Thank you!